# Get specific value from disassembled file in C# .Net

Tags: c#, disassembly, capstone

I have a script in C# that uses the [Gee.Capstone](https://github.com/9ee1/Capstone.NET) package to automate disassembling files. I am not familiar with the whole concept so I just try to do what I need based on online tutorials.

I have a few virtual addresses in the format of range. For example: `0x0122FFB0-0x01230028`

When I disassembly the file with another GUI, such as Cutter, I get something like this

```
0x0122ffb0      stp x20, x19, [sp, -0x20]!
0x0122ffb4      stp x29, x30, [sp, 0x10]
0x0122ffb8      add x29, sp, 0x10
0x0122ffbc      ldr x8, [x0, 8]    ; fcn.00000008
0x0122ffc0      mov x19, x0
0x0122ffc4      orr w1, wzr, 2
0x0122ffc8      mov x2, xzr
0x0122ffcc      ldr x20, [x8]
0x0122ffd0      mov x0, x20
0x0122ffd4      bl fcn.0304bf80
0x0122ffd8      mov x0, x20
.....
0x0122fffc      ldr x8, [x19, 8]   ; fcn.00000008
```

I want to get the value 2 from `orr w1, wzr, 2`. In general, the values I want are always in the format of `orr w1, wzr X`, but it's not always in the same order in the range of the two addresses.

Assuming that I have a list with all the ranges, is there any way to identify the row I need and grab the `X` value?

The closer I have been is this

```
private static CapstoneX86Disassembler asm = CapstoneX86Disassembler.CreateX86Disassembler(X86DisassembleMode.Bit64);
var obj = asm.Disassemble(att.GetMethodBody(), (long)att.VirtualAddress.Start);
```

where the `att` is the object I have stored the ranges of the Virtual Addresses with the `Start` and the `End` of it. However, I cannot find any way to get the info I need from the `obj` object then.

Edit: It is not necessary to keep using Capstone. If there is a solution to get that with another package, I am ok with it.